# Counting numbers of areas and rectangulars by 2-d array in c

Tags: c

In a 2-D array only consisting of 1 and 0, 0 means a space and 1 means a wall. [Matrix example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4LnR.png)

And the prototype of the function is

```
int numberOfArea (int area[20][20],int height, int width, int *result);
int numberOfRect (int area[20][20],int height, int width, int *result);
```

The intended return for situation in matrix example is

numberOfArea returns 0, and *result = 4

numberOfRect returns 0, and *result = 2

If the calculation is done normally, they return 0. Otherwise, when inappropriate values are entered like below, it returns 1.

1. If other values(rather than 0 or 1)are entered in the area array
2. If the value of height or width exceeds 20.

---

I tried to solve this problem by counting numbers of continuous 0's numbers.
For example, If I get input as picture, I set up a new array that includes

```
1 2 3 0 1

1 2 0 1 2

0 0 0 0 0

1 2 0 1 2

1 2 0 1 2
```

Then I can calculate the numbers of rectangulars by comparing up line and down line. But I don't know how writing the code.

And I have no idea how I can write code about calculating numbers of areas :(

numbers of Areas means if we consider 1 as wall, and 0 as blank space, the number of space we can distinct from other space by walls.

Comment: "I have no idea how I can write code about calculating numbers of areas" is too broad.  What specifically is the problem?

Comment: Does the function `numberOfArea` have to return the number of distinct areas, where an area is a zone of contiguous 0 ? What is the function `numberOfRect` expected to return ? What is considered a rect ?

Comment: Please edit your question explaining the expected output of each function and post what you did so far.

Comment: Perhaps a look at the [Sweep Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) may be useful. You would want to work both directions with your `1` walls was bounds.You would need to keep a length of each sequence of zeros within a bounded region to determine if the region was a rectangle (any variation of zero sequence length horizontally or vertically within a region would preclude it from being a rectangular region).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm for `numberOfArea` is the following.

Scan the area row by row, from top left to bottom right. If the cell we visit has value 0, we found a new area. We then increment the area counter and set the value of all cells of this area to the value 2. We call this process tagging an area. When the scan is finished, we have the count of distinct areas. We then do a last scan to restore the values to 0.

For tagging we use a recursive function. It does nothing if the cell coordinates are invalid or the cell value is not 0. Otherwise it sets the cell value to 2, and tags the four neighbor cells.

```c
void tagArea(int area[20][20],int height, int width, int i, int j) {
    if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= height || j >= width || area[i][j] != 0)
        return;
    area[i][j] = 2;
    tagArea(area, height, width, i-1, j);
    tagArea(area, height, width, i+1, j);
    tagArea(area, height, width, i, j-1);
    tagArea(area, height, width, i, j+1);
}

int numberOfArea(int area[20][20],int height, int width, int *result) {
    // verify validity of arguments
    if(width > 20 || height > 20)
        return 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            if(area[i][j] < 0 || area[i][j] > 1)
                return 1;
    *result = 0;
    // count and tag every untagged area
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if(area[i][j] == 0) {
                (*result)++;
                tagArea(area, height, width, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    // clear tags
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            if(area[i][j] == 2)
                area[i][j] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code of the other function:

```c
int numberOfRect(int area[20][20],int height, int width, int *result) {
    // verify validity of arguments
    if(width > 20 || height > 20)
        return 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            if(area[i][j] < 0 || area[i][j] > 1)
                return 1;
    *result = 0;
    // for every untagged cell...
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if(area[i][j] != 0)
                continue;
            // measure width and height of rectangle
            int w = 0, h = 0;
            for(int k = j; k < width && area[i][k] == 0; k++)
                w++;
            for(int k = i; k < height && area[k][j] == 0; k++)
                h++;            
            // assert top is border or all wall, otherwise the area would have been tagged
            // if left is not border and not all wall, it’s not a rectangle
            if(j > 0)
                for(int k = i; k < i+h; k++)
                    if(area[k][j-1] != 1)
                        goto tagging; 
            // if right is not border and not all wall, it’s not a rectangle
            if(j + w < width)
                for(int k = i; k < i+h; k++)
                    if(area[k][j+w] != 1)
                        goto tagging;
            // if bottom is not border and not all wall, it’s not a rectangle
            if(i + h < height)
                for(int k = j; k < j+w; k++)
                    if(area[i+h][k] != 1)
                        goto tagging;
            // make sure no wall is inside the rectangle
            for(int k = i; k < i+h; k++)
                for(int l = j; l < j+w; l++)
                    if(area[k][l] != 0)
                        goto tagging;
            // all conditions are met, area is a rectangle
            (*result)++;
    tagging:
            tagArea(area, width, height, i, j);
        }            
    }
    // clear tags
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            if(area[i][j] == 2)
                area[i][j] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code of the main function to test the other functions:

```c
int main() {
    int height = 5, width = 5, result;
    int area[20][20] = {
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
        {1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
    };

    /*
    printf("The size of the width: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("The size of the height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Please enter your array\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
            printf("[%d,%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &area[i][j]);
        }
    }
    */
    // print area
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", area[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    if(numberOfArea(area, height, width, &result) == 0) {
        printf("Number of closed spaces: %d\n", result);
    } else {
        printf("Number of closed spaces: invalid width, height or grid value\n");
    }
    if(numberOfRect(area, height, width, &result) == 0) {
        printf("Number of rectangular spaces: %d\n", result);
    } else {
        printf("Number of rectangular spaces: invalid width, height or grid value\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have one more question.Is it possible to make copy of area[] to avoid restoring the value?

Comment: It is possible, but less trivial and efficient. As long as you restore the map, it shouldn’t matter.

Comment: See full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59153749/75517)

Comment: oh.. It says page not found... and If you need more specific details, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126147/counting-numbers-of-rectangulars-in-2d-array)  here is more detailed explain.

Comment: The question  was deleted. I updated my answer with the missing function and a main function to test the code. Note that I update the first function which had a few errors. The code now runs and execute as expected.